# Empty review queue spacing

Tags: discussion, review-queues, design

Below you see the landing page for an empty review queue.

I can't help but feel that when these two lines are the only lines, there should be some padding at the bottom of the text, as it feels a little cramped right now.

[image: empty review queue]

I suggest adding `margin-bottom: 5px;` (anywhere between `2px` and `5px`) to `<div class="review-summary">` when it is the last child.

To allay potential confusion, I've indicated *"the bottom of the text"* with a green arrow below:

[image: empty review queue with arrow]

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Minor alignment issue in the review summary box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325815/289905).